# vue-next-level-scroll force it click after DOM is rendered. Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am using this vue-next-level-scroll from
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-next-level-scroll.

I would like this action to be triggered immediately after a component is rendered.

In my vue file, I have the following code

```
<vue-next-level-scroll ref="myBtn" :target='`#${this.postIdQuery}`'>
   <button @click='iGotCliked()'>Click me!</button>
</vue-next-level-scroll>
```

In my vue file script tag, I have the following updated function to get the ref of the button and force it to click.

```
updated: function () {
    if (this.postIdQuery != null) {
      const elem = this.$refs.myBtn
      elem.click()
    }
  }
```

In the dom, the id of the target has already been set. This code works when i click on the 'Click me!' button. However, i want vue to click on render so that it will automatically scroll to the desired element when a user enters that component/page. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your updated() lifecycle hook to mounted(). Then try it should work.

Comment: I have changed it to mounted but it still does not work